# Ecommerce and Jquery hover buttons show basket or login?

Tags: jquery, button, e-commerce, mouseover, shopping-cart

I am currently building an ecommerce site using oscommerce. (However i'm open to suggestions as to which open source patform is the best and what i should really use. Magneto, ZenCart, etc)

I am looking to add jquery to give the store better interaction and usability...

For example,

I would like to create a button that on mouseover allows the user either to type in their login details, or view a shopping basket, etc.

The perfect example is Apple's breadcrumb navbar, when you hover over their basket or account, etc.

I'm limited to using mysql and php so using apples java web tore is not an option.

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the jQuery script, can you be more detailed in your question?

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('my-hover-element').hover(function(){
      $('my-box-element').stop(true,true).toggleSlide(100);
   });
});
```

So the "my-hover-element" would be the trigger and the "my-box-element" would be the div where you have the form or whatever you want.

I hope it's what you want.

Comment: I want a button in the form of an image (shopping cart or user button) which when you hover over with your mouse, will display a box that allows you to either login or another box which will display the contents of your shopping cart.